# Is there a way to notify subscribers of changes made to a shared Google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

Is there a way to notify subscribers of a calendar when changes are made?

Comment: What changes are you talking about? Do you mean alerting people on the calendar when new events are added/changed? Or do you mean when settings are changed for the particular calendar?

Comment: Have you seen [this help page](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37503?hl=en)?